# There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jsp

This is a simple Spring Boot Hello World Example – with JSP. but when I try to access http://localhost:8080/welcome on my browser it gives the following error on my browser.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment
```

------------And in my STS tool throws the following run time error----------

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.INameEnvironment
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]


    2019-04-09 14:20:07.813 ERROR 6424 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment] with root cause
```

```
----------Root cause looks this--------
2019-04-09 19:43:03.050 ERROR 10124 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.INameEnvironment
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:155) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Images of directory and errors are here on google drive

### [Images of directory and errors are here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qr5ZEikPVCbUiqaZvi770FmFFmHbYrbQ?usp=sharing)

[This is the eclipse console erer message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSdFo.jpg)

------------------DemoApplication --------------------

```
    package com.example.demo;

            import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
            import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

            @SpringBootApplication
            @ComponentScan("com.*")
            public class DemoApplication {

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
                }

            }
    --------------------ApplicationController --------------------------------
        package com.example.demo.controller;

        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


        @Controller
        public class ApplicationController {
        @RequestMapping("/welcome")
            public String welcome() {
                return "welcome";
            }
        }

    ----------------------application.properties------------------------------
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

----------------------welcome.jsp--------------------------------
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is my test page for Jsp!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
-----------------pom.xml---------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I am trying to return a JSP page from this spring boot simple application. I added tomcat-embed-jasper dependences. But this problem throws by the compile when I try to access http://localhost:8080/welcome in my browser.

Comment: You should post an example of code rather than a link. We dont have access to that link anyway.

Comment: Thanks, August please check those codes

Comment: What wa the text you omitted after 'with root cause'? The part that answers the question?

Comment: I put the root cause check it now

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the annoying error for me. I spent 2 weeks on checking my code, dependencies, and my sts configuration too. There is no single answer on the internet too. 
The solution for this error is 
1. Open my IDE(STS tool) 
2. Click on Help from the top menu
3. Select Check for Updates
4. Select all the available updates and Select update, once the update completed 
5. Restart my STS Tool, Then right click on my project, go to Maven and select Update project. Now everything works fine as my expectation,

Answer (score 0):

```
In my case it worked by adding this dependency in pom.xml
It is needed to compile jsp tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```